# how to save pdf file in client machine in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I generate a pdf file on the fly and save it to the server side but i need to save it to the client machine. How to achieve this..

```
 Document doc = new Document();
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
 string PDFName = ProjectName + ".pdf";
 PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/ProjectFiles") + "/" + 
 PDFName, FileMode.Create));
 doc.Open();
       //PDF Content
 doc.Close();

 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + PDFName);
 Response.Buffer = true;
 Response.Clear();
 Response.OutputStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, memoryStream.GetBuffer().Length);
 Response.OutputStream.Flush();
 Response.End();

     In Response.OutputStream.Write(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, memoryStream.GetBuffer().Length);
```

The memoryStream length is 0. I need to download the saved pdf into Cleint machine.
Please help me to fix this issue..

Comment: It seems you don't fill memoryStream anywhere. Use FileStream in OutputStream.Write the same as in PdfWriter.GetInstance.

Comment: How to write @mswietlicki... any code?

Comment: Does it save on the server - can you open the pdfs?

Comment: yes it save on the server.. yes i can open it..

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing anything to `memoryStream`.

Since you are generating PDFs on each request there is no need to save them to the file. You could generate the PDF to the `MemoryStream` directly.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memoryStream);
```

If your PDFs are not dynamic (eg. there is no need to generate them on every request) You can generate them to the file system as you do right now and then only read them from disk:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
{
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(YourPdfFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
        file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
        ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
    }
}
```

But this makes sens only if the PDFs are generated once and then only served from disk.

EDIT: after writing into stream it was necessary to set memoryStream position to zero because it was at the end.

Comment: here the memorystream.getbuffer length is = threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' and it wont be saved on client side

Comment: Any details? Which solution did you try?

Comment: But why? What's the problem? Is the memory stream empty? Are there any exceptions? Did you try to connect with debugger any checking position in the stream? Maybe you should reset the stream after it was written? Give me some information to help you.

Comment: i used, PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/ProjectFiles") + "/" + 
 PDFName, FileMode.Create));  instead of memoryStream..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36548/discussion-between-szymon-kuzniak-and-jasper-manickaraj)

Comment: i just fixed it... All your code was right but i used $.Ajax() method in javascript.. Instead of this i just used window.location.href= "Calling Controller Action".

Answer (score 0):

You have to affect memorystream like that :

```
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
```